# LogicApp custom connector dynamic schema response fields

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm using custom connector and trying to populate dynamic schema response

Using `x-ms-dynamic-schema`

This is my swagger:

```
  responses:
    '200':
      description: Result
      schema:
        description: output description
        type: object
        x-ms-dynamic-schema:
          operationId: OperationId
          parameters:
            ref: {parameter: ref}
          value-path: output
```

And this is the UI dynamic content:

[image]

Question is why am I seeing also `Body` and `Item` fields while they are not appearing in my schema response:

```
{
    'output': {
        'type': 'object',
        'properties': {
            'some_field1': {
                'type': 'string',
                'required': True
            },
            'some_field2': {
                'type': 'string',
                'required': True
            },
            'some_field3': {
                'required': True,
                'type': 'array',
                'items': {
                    'type': 'number'
                }
            },
            'some_field4': {
                'required': True,
                'type': 'integer'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, Body and Item are inbuilt objects for any result from previous steps, that are listed under dynamic content .

Comment: @AjayKumarGhose-MT So ```Body``` is the whole response body? But what ```Item``` refer to?

Comment: Hello @David Meu, Basically When the previous result has more than one object in its entity, it provides a variable as `item` which refers to each entity from result & and `Body` is just whole reference to the result or response from the earlier step, it is json of complete result as it is.

Comment: This is a bit odd that: ```Body and Item are inbuilt objects``` 
Because they are not appearing in other connectors responses (Outlook 365 for example)

Comment: Yeah it is inbuilt objects  for such connectors which we have created. Even in Outlook 365 for example we can get body in dynamic content as well.

Comment: Can you please assist me with this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70767340/azure-custom-connector-working-with-localhost

Comment: Sure let me check . Can i post this same as an answer so it will be helpful for other community members for this similar query.

Comment: Yes,
Would appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @David Meu, For confirmation. Posting it as an answer to help other community members.

> Question is why am I seeing also Body and Item fields while they are
> not appearing in my schema response:

AFAIK, **Body and Item are inbuilt objects** for any result from previous steps, that are listed under dynamic content.
When the previous result has more than **one object** in its entity, it provides a variable as **item** which refers to each entity from result so you can easily refer in looping activities to iterate.
and **Body** is just whole reference to the result or response from the earlier step, it is `json` of complete result as it is.

> Because they are not appearing in other connectors responses (Outlook
> 365 for example)

We can see the body field (e.g) in `Outlook 365` .For activities which have results will only produce that option .so its depends on the activity .

[image]

For more information please refer this ***Microsoft Documentation***: [***Call an API from a Logic Apps workflow using a custom connector***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/logic-apps-and-custom-connectors/) & [***Extend an OpenAPI definition for a custom connector***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/openapi-extensions#use-dynamic-schema)