# Azure custom connector working with localhost

Tags: azure, localhost, power-automate, connector

I tried using that guide:
https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/on-premise-apis/

To work with my localhost running server with azure custom connector.

I've defined an API gateway and my local server is running but receiving:

```
    {
      "error": {
        "code": 500,
        "message": "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8000",
        "source": "unitedstates-002.azure-apim.net",
        "path": "forward-request",
        "policyId": "",
        "clientRequestId": "70655628-faaa-4725-8ea1-4b8a-e599385d"
      }
    }
```

When testing my connector.

My local server is at: http://127.0.0.1:8000

My gateway:
[image]

My custom connector connection creation:
[image]

My connector gateway settings:
[image]

Note that:

This is power automate custom connector.

**The Only diff is that I'm using the url from `apiProperties.json` file
`"x-ms-apimTemplateParameter.urlTemplate": "http://127.0.0.1:8000"`**

If I'm using localhost in the swagger host everything is fine.

Comment: Hello @David Meu, Could you please refer this https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Can-t-connect-to-localhost-Visual-Studio-API-via-Custom/td-p/311577 .

Comment: I've followed it I have an api gateway online+I've configured what is needed in my CC but still. edited the post.

Comment: BTW which IP should I use as the custom connector host? (In Logicapp custom connector I've Used localhost i.e 127.0.0.1:8000) Because in the guide I saw he is using his machine IP

Comment: May i know if you are using your own IP address or not.!

Comment: I tried with my localhost,public,private ip's and port 8000. with all of those I've received errs.

Comment: I see why it is not working! because I'm using the url from ```apiProperties.json``` urlTemplate seems it doesn't like it :| so I've created a connector only with the swagger and it is working.

Comment: Let me check on my environment and get back to you..!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241241/discussion-between-david-meu-and-ajaykumarghose-mt).